# Encrypting C:\Users on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt C:\Users on Windows 7?

I've tried TrueCrypt with whole partition encryption and it doesn't work because I don't have 32kb free in my boot sector (Apple's Boot Camp I presume). I've created an encrypted module with the intention of mounting it on U:\ and have that be users, but I cannot configure system-favirotes mounts with TrueCrypt because of the same 32kb problem.

BitLocker is not an option because I don't have the hardware requirements.

Is there any other options? Would PGP Desktop work here?

Comment: Hey, Mark, you should put that into an answer, it seems like that's the solution. If you don't create the answer I'll do it myself but I think you deserve the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No TPM? You can actually [use BitLocker without a TPM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424299(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: More information on http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/4681-bitlocker-drive-encryption-windows-7-drive-turn-off-no-tpm.html