# Mac questions: installing TrueCrypt and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mac, multi-boot, encryption, boot-camp

I'm about to buy a Mac laptop, but I need to be able to use Windows 7 as well + encrypt the HDD with TrueCrypt (or a better alternative for the mac).

My questions are:

1. How well does Windows 7 perform under boot camp?
2. Will I be able to encrypt the whole HDD (with TrueCrypt or whatever else) and still use boot camp to dual-boot?

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Windows 7 runs at full speed under bootcamp. Bootcamp is not an emulator or virtual machine, simply a utility which makes it easier to install Windows - otherwise your intel-based Mac is not that different from any other PC laptop.

2) According to [this document](http://blog.taggesell.de/index.php?/archives/36-TrueCrypt-on-Macbook-Windows-XP.html) and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/23501/windows-with-truecrypt-and-mac-os-x-on-the-same-machine), Truecrypt has issues with Windows not being the first partition when doing a full drive encryption because it expects Windows to be the first partition on the drive, and people haven't been too successful even with installing a custom bootloader. I would recommend using Windows 7's Bitlocker Drive encryption if your version has this feature if you wish to dualboot both windows and Macos x.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 performs very well on the Macbook Pro's I have tested on.  32 and 64 bit versions are supported.  Gaming is noticeably faster on the Windows side of a Macbook Pro than the 10.6.3 side ...

You will not be able to use full disk encryption with Truecrypt.  You may look into a pay solution such as PGP Desktop.

Truecrypt works very well on both systems.  One option you may consider is creating a third partition, calling it DATA, and using TC to encrypt that.